# making eye sockets (bird)

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to sculpt a head of a bird, and when i try to sculpt the eyelids, they are lumpy and clip into the eyeball, Is there any way to sculpt a smooth socket that wont clip into the eyeball and fit it perfectly?I've attached an image of my mesh and an image of what i want to achieve:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this "precise fit" can be done with sculpting. You could use a boolean modifier and subtract the eye, but that would not create a nice topo mesh.

Can you explain a bit more why it is a problem to ave the eyelid "clip" into the eye slightly. Most people do it that way when modelling eyes because perfect fit sometimes can give render issues like shadows or gaps.
As for the bulging, could you post a close-up of the mesh around the eye?

cheers,

Comment: well clipping produces an uneven edge for me, however if an even clipping edge can be made then that would be fine for me. i've replaced the picture of my mesh with a closer up one.

Comment: I'm no expert on sculpting so just to be sure:Is the unevenness caused by the eye, or by the mesh of the eye-socket? Did you subsurface the eye and set it to smooth? ...Sorry editing is not working well ...

Comment: Like I sayed editing is not working well...I'm no expert on sculpting so just to be sure: Is the unevenness caused by the eye, or by the mesh of the eye-socket? Did you subsurface the eye and set it to smooth? could you post an image of the bird (&eye-socket) head in edit mode so the mesh is visible?

Comment: I think i have more or less sorted out the issue, I made the eye socket too deep which in turn stretched all of the faces around the edge of the eye, making impossible to use brushes on that area without distorting the edge. Thanks for the help nonetheless.